# Simple Autosomal Recessive question by a novice genetics student

Tags: genetics, dna, allele

How do you figure the percentage of offspring that will be a carrier of an Autosomal Recessive gene when the **FATHER** is the recessive carrier and the **MOTHER** is not affected (normal, no recessive)?  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Do your cross diagram and multiply the correct combinations together:

Father: Rr

Mother: RR

Since it's autosomal:

Chance of getting R from father: 50%

Chance of getting r from father: 50%

Chance of getting R from mother: 100%

You're looking for the chance of receiving Rr, which requires r from the father and R from the mother.